# Can not find some dependencies while building dremio-oss

Tags: apache-arrow, dremio

https://github.com/dremio/dremio-oss/blob/master/pom.xml

After I clone the project,I try to build the project, but some dependencies are not found .How to find these dependencies,such as
[the project accquire calicte:4.0.0-20210722102535-bda216e83f-dremio,which can not find in mavencenter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuwRK.png) 
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried building dremio-oss on Windows the other day and there were no problems with resolving dependencies.  You should include more information from the build log.  You can also try using the "-U" option to force checking remote repositories which is useful if your local repository cache is out of date.  Your error message also doesn't make sense since the correct version for Calcite is this one:  https://github.com/dremio/dremio-oss/blob/master/pom.xml#L46